# Module build failed: SyntaxError: D://React/git_react/Notetaker/app/config/routes.js: Unexpected token (8:4)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to React and I was using router for routing the components. But I am getting this error when I do the module.exports:

> ERROR in ./app/config/routes.js Module build failed: SyntaxError:
>   D:/KumarYa1/Workplace/React/git_react/Notetaker/app/config/routes.js:
>   Unexpected token (8:4)
>    6 |

```
module.exports = {   {<*Route path="/" component={Main}><*/Route>*} };
                     ^
```

> ```
> at Parser.pp$5.raise (D:\KumarYa1\Workplace\React\git_react\Notetaker\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4443:13)
> at Parser.pp.unexpected (D:\KumarYa1\Workplace\React\git_react\Notetaker\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1755:8)
> at Parser.pp$3.parseIdentifier (D:\KumarYa1\Workplace\React\git_react\Notetaker\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4321:10)
> at Parser.pp$3.parsePropertyName (D:\KumarYa1\Workplace\React\git_react\Notetaker\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4145:96)
> at Parser.parsePropertyName (D:\KumarYa1\Workplace\React\git_react\Notetaker\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:6089:23)
> at Parser.pp$3.parseObj (D:\KumarYa1\Workplace\React\git_react\Notetaker\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4035:12)
> at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (D:\KumarYa1\Workplace\React\git_react\Notetaker\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3709:19)
> at Parser.parseExprAtom (D:\KumarYa1\Workplace\React\git_react\Notetaker\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:7096:22)
> at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\KumarYa1\Workplace\React\git_react\Notetaker\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3484:19)
> at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (D:\KumarYa1\Workplace\React\git_react\Notetaker\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3464:19)
> ```
>
> @ ./app/App.js 6:13-39

App.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var routes = require('./config/routes');

ReactDOM.render(
        <Router>{routes}</Router>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    )
```

routes.js:

```
var React = require('react');
    var Main = require('../components/Main');
    var Home = require('../components/Home');
    var Router = require('react-router');
    var Route = Router.Route;
module.exports = {

    <Route path="/" component={Main}></Route> 

};
```

Main.js:

```
var React = require('react');

  var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
      return(
        <div>
          Hello World
        </div>
      )
    }
  });

module.exports = Main;
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app/App.js",
  output: {
    filename: "public/bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: your file is in fact a `.jsx` not `.js`, you should use a transpiler like `babel` to convert it

Comment: No actually I used curly braces instead of small brackets. It got resolved. Thanks anyways :)